# Replacing "this" with real value

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Right now I have this piece of code in a function:

```
oTrack = json.played_tracks[0];

eA = $("<a/>")
.addClass("hugetile")
.attr("href","#"+0)
.appendTo(o)
.click(function(){
    cont.getDetails($(this),"lastsong",18);
    console.log($(this)) 
});
```

Now: I would like to be able to replace "this" with a real value.

The console.log displays: `Object[a.hugetile #0]`

However simply replacing "$(this)" with "Object[a.hugetile #0]" results in a big ol' error.

The reason I need it without "this" is because I want the function to instantly perform the .click function (so that it triggers without a user having to click). But at the moment this is impossible because I can't have `cont.getDetails($(this),"lastsong",18);`
as standalone code. (this is unknown)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply trigger a click

```
oTrack = json.played_tracks[0];

eA = $("<a/>")
.addClass("hugetile")
.attr("href","#"+0)
.appendTo(o)
.click(function(){
    cont.getDetails($(this),"lastsong",18);
    console.log($(this)) 
}).click();
```

---

Calling

```
cont.getDetails(eA,"lastsong",18);
```

right after should work without the flash. `eA` is equivalent to `$(this)` in the click handler.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This works but now you see the original content "flash" a second before the click happens :/

Comment: I wonder if `.triggerHandler("click")` should be used instead of `.click()`. It avoids default behaviors on elements, and other issues.

Answer (score 2):

Triggering the click event immediately would be the best approach. However, to give you a better understanding of `this` inside the event handler, you could also do the following:

```
eA = $("<a/>")
    .addClass("hugetile")
    .attr("href", "#" + 0)
    .appendTo(o)
    .click(function () {
        cont.getDetails($(this), "lastsong", 18);
        console.log($(this))
    });

cont.getDetails(eA, "lastsong", 18);
```

Inside the event handler, `this` refers to the DOM element you created with `$("<a/>")`. But so does `eA`. `eA` is a jQuery object which contains that DOM element, hence `eA` and `$(this)` are both jQuery objects which contain the same DOM element.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this doesn't seem to work, the click event does though.

Comment: What can I say. If the code is as you posted it, it should work. Simplified example: http://jsfiddle.net/q86u2/.